# Multiple Options for IF an IF function

Tags: python-2.7, if-statement

So I want to write it so IF 's' is NOT equal to 1, 2 or 3, then it prints error. Otherwise, if it IS equal to 1, 2, or 3, it goes on to print something else.

> ```
> s = raw_input("Between 1-3: ")
>     if s != 1, 2 or 3:
>         print "ERROR"
>     else:
>         print "******"
> ```

Comment: try `if s not in [1, 2, 3]`

Comment: It did not work, I entered 1, 2 and 3 and 4 and I got error each time

Comment: that's because s is a string, try `if int(s) not in [1, 2, 3]`

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
 if not (1 <= int(s) <= 3):
    print "ERROR"
 else:
    print "******"
```

Updates: `raw_input` gives you a string you must convert to an integer or float before making any numeric comparison.